# How to differentiate between character and vector of character in R

Tags: r, types

I am quite new to R and its intricacies. I have a situation wherein I have to differentiate whether the user keyed in a value to a variable as character or as a vector of characters. What condition can I use to differentiate between the following syntax provided below?

```
c1 <- "text"
c2 <- c("text")
```

Type of c1 and c2 returns `character` and `c1 == c2` returns `TRUE`. Does R treat both (c1 and c2) to be inherently same or does it give a workaround to indicate they are different and if so how?

Comment: R doesn't have scalars, so both `c1` and `c2` would be a vector of length 1. You can check if it's a vector of characters by checking the `length`

Answer (score 0):

As noted by avid, the c() function is merely a sequence of items.  Note what happens here:

```
c1 <- c(1, 2)
c2 <- 3
c3 <- c(c1, c2)
c3
[1] 1 2 3
c4 <- "4"
c5 <- c(c3, c4)
> c5
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

c3 appends c2 to the vector c1, c5 is an example of coercion in R.  I.e. since c4 is a character value every element of c5 is coerced to character.

Answer (score 0):

Since both your examples result in a vector, your best bet is to compare `length(c1) == 1`. If the length is equal to 1, `c1` *probably* is a character.

You can also see it in the Documentation for `is.string` in the searchable package, more precisely in the description of argument `x` [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/searchable/versions/0.3.3.1/topics/is.string).

[image: is.string Documentation]

For accessibility reasons, I'll provide an R example here.

```
checkIfString <- function(v) {
  # must be of type character and a vector with a single element
  is.character(v) && length(v) == 1
}

checkIfString("I'm a string") # TRUE
checkIfString(c("still tru")) # TRUE
checkIfString(c("now", "na")) # FALSE
checkIfString(c(12345.12345)) # FALSE
```